# Angular 2 Teamcity erro

Tags: node.js, angular, build, npm, teamcity

```
Hi I am getting below error in teamcity can any one help me out here.

[05:40:13][Step 1/6] Update assembly versions: Scanning checkout directory for assembly information related files to update version to 12
[05:40:13][Step 1/6] scan: Searching for nuget.config files
[05:40:13][Step 1/6] install: Installing NuGet packages for packages.config (7s)
[05:40:20]Step 2/6: NPM Install (Node.js NPM) (56s)
[05:40:20][Step 2/6] npm install (56s)
[05:40:20][npm install] Executing npm via wrapping shell script
[05:40:20][npm install] Starting: cmd /c npm install
[05:40:20][npm install] in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a3b3f663c6e5a358\Source
[05:41:10][npm install] WARN engine angular2-cookie@1.2.3: wanted: {"node":">=5.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"3.4.0"})
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\svcTeamCityBuildA\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! node v4.2.2
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! npm  v3.4.0
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! code E404
[05:41:16][npm install] 
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 Not Found: artifactory
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 'artifactory' is not in the npm registry.
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'SmartText'
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
[05:41:16][npm install] 
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[05:41:16][npm install] npm ERR!     D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a3b3f663c6e5a358\Source\npm-debug.log
[05:41:16][npm install] Process exited with code 1
[05:41:16][Step 2/6] Step NPM Install (Node.js NPM) failed
[05:41:16]Step 3/6: Build Typescript files (Gulp)
[05:41:16]Step 4/6: Build app (Visual Studio (sln))`enter code here`
[05:41:16]Step 5/6: Copy deploy.yml and app files (Command Line)
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "SmartText",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Smart Text",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "compile": "gulp compile",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "start": "concurrent --kill-others \"gulp watch\" \"lite-server\"",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "Ranjeet Singh",
  "license": "MOD",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "install": "^0.8.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.0.24",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.3",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: What Artifactory version are you using? do you have any proxy in front of your Artifactory instance?

Answer (score 0):

The 404 means there is no `artifactory` module in npm.  Search npm for the right one, perhaps `artifactory-api`? https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=artifactory

Comment: Hi actually this is not the exact missing package. it gives at random